# In NEURON simulator, how do you pan and zoom a plotted graph?

Tags: computational-modeling, software

How do I zoom in and move around a chart after it has been plotted?

Answer (score 1):

Unintuitive, but it's in the right click > View sub-menu:

**Pan/translate**:

1. Right click the chart
2. View > Translate
3. Left click drag will pan around the chart

**Zoom**:

1. Right click the chart
2. View > Zoom In/Out
3. Left click drag horizontally or vertically to zoom the x or y axis

**Zoom in on a region**:

1. Right click the chart
2. View > NewView
3. Left click on the chart to draw a box
4. A new window will open, drag the lower-right corner to expand the window